# Custom product not able to save after m2 upgrade

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I have upgrade magento version from 2.1.5 to 2.1.14.
I have create custom module to create custom option with the reference of this "https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-custom-options-programmatically-in-magento-2/" page.

After magento upgrade when i trying to create custom option after few minutes browser gives 503 error and not getting any error in log files.

I have try to debug and found some issue with this  `$option->save();` method.

Comment: you might have permission issue. Please give proper permission to pub/ and generated and to  var directory and  try.

Comment: Already check with permission , but still not working.